# Implement intent into FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

Am trying to implement tab fragment. if i touch one tab in want to start new activity. in this case i used intent to start new activity but it not working. How can add intent here.

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {

        case 0:
            Intent intent = new Intent(new MainActivity(), Alarm.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if i touch one tab in want to start new activity

A `FragmentPagerAdapter` shows **Fragments** from the `getItem()` method. It doesn't start Activities.

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment f = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            f = new AlarmFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;  // returning null could cause errors, though

    }
    return f;
}
```

---

If you really want this feature, though

1) `new Intent()` takes a `Context`, not an `Activity` explicitly.

2) Never ever make `new SomeActivity()` because it is unmanaged and you get problems.

Like any other adapter, you may pass a `Context`

```
private Context mContext;
public PagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}
```

And use that

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.mContext, Alarm.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? PagerAdapter changes Fragments in a ViewPager.
You need a [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html), if you want start activity on tab item click.
But if you want change pages, you have to return a Fragment in *getItem(int position)* method